# Strange error while reinstalling 12.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, 64-bit, live-cd

So I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) to an external HDD.

I select where I want the swap area, the boot loader, etc (the "something else" option). That all works fine, then I click "Install Now", it then starts formatting my HDD and copying files. Great.

I then fill out the "Where are you" window and click continue, I then fill out the "Who are you" window (all fields are green, username is all lower case). And then I click the "Continue" button, then the mouse turns into the "clock" <strike>and the installer continues to copy files. But when it finishes copying (progress bar is full) the progress bar then vanishes and nothing happens, the "Who are you" window is still displayed, the mouse is still the "clock". Absolutely nothing changes (except for the progress bar).</strike>

**Update**

I cancelled the installation then restarted the installer, but this time I selected the "Reinstall Ubuntu 12.04.3 LST" (or something like that), it then installs, but now I get a sort-of blue screen error (but with a black screen instead) when it starts to install grub 2.

First line of the error...

```
[1276.066187] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00000000bd80819c
```

A few lines later...

```
[1276.068391]    call trace
[1276.068391] [<ffffffff81054bd6>] ? efi_call4+0x46/0x80
```

There's then a few more lines of the call trace, but I only copied the last call.

This looks like a bug to me, but if it's not, what can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. What I actually ended up doing was creating a Live-USB on my external HDD then installed from that to my smaller memory stick. Now everything works perfectly fine.